# remove UITableView Section background color in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with 7 sections and i want to remove that existing "Light grey " color of UITableView section (default color )to "Transparent color".

I tried this code and its not working please help me.

Code

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *tempView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,300,244)];
    tempView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *tempLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,0,300,44)];
    tempLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    tempLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tempLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,2);
    tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; //here you can change the text color of header.
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    NSString *sectionName;
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Mobile Number", @"Mobile Number");
            break;
        case 1:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Name", @"Name");
            break;
        case 2:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Email", @"Email");
            break;
        case 3:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Gender", @"Gender");
            break;
        case 4:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Age", @"Age");
            break;
        case 5:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Notes", @"Notes");
            break;
        case 6:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@" Type", @" Type");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    tempLabel.text=sectionName;

    [tempView addSubview:tempLabel];

    return tempView;
}
```

Comment: are you not using storyboard/nib?

Comment: https://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/ios-how-to-customize-table-view-header-and-footer-colors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` requires that you also implement:

- `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`. This should return an appropriate `non-zero height` for the header.
- Also make sure you do not also implement the `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`.

You should only use one or the other (`viewForHeader` or
    `titleForHeader`).